Origin of $1/v$ region of neutron capture cross section and different Breit-Wigner formula formulations
I'm studying neutron radiative capture reactions and was wondering about the origin of the so called "$1/v$ region".
Here's the region I'm referring to:

Apart from being an experimental observation, the only explanation I seemed to find was from Duderstadt's Nuclear Reactor Analysis (1976), page 26-27, as a low energy limit of the Breit - Wigner formula

$$ \sigma_\gamma(E_c) = \sigma_0\frac{\Gamma_\gamma}{\Gamma}\left(\frac{E_0}{E_c}\right)^{1/2}\frac{1}{1+y^2},\quad y=\frac{2}{\Gamma}\left(E_c-E_0\right).  $$

where    $\sigma_0 = 4\pi g\ \large{ƛ}^2_0\frac{\Gamma_n}{\Gamma}$.
Since, he says, $\Gamma_n \propto \sqrt E$ one can conclude that

For low energies $E<<E_0$, the cross section behaves as essentially
$1/E^{1/2}$ or $1/v$.

If one goes through the effort of actually substituting y and $\sigma_0$ in the cross section formula, unless I am mistaken, should find something like this:
$$\sigma_\gamma(E)= \frac{\pi}{k^2}g\left(\frac{E_0}{E}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\Gamma_n \Gamma_\gamma}{(E-E_0)^2+\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}}$$
where I have substituted $k=1/\lambda$, since that is the usual way I found the BW formula written in Bertulani's Nuclear Physics in a Nutshell, 2007 (page 288, eq. 10.87) and Krane's Introductory Nuclear Physics, 1988 (page 428, eq. 11.70), that is
$$\sigma= \frac{\pi}{k^2}g \frac{\Gamma_{aX} \Gamma_{bY}}{(E-E_R)^2+\Gamma^2/4}$$
Two questions:

In Duderstadt's formulation we have a $\left(\frac{E_0}{E}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ factor not present in the other two. I don't know how to reconcile the two formulations.
I don't know how to replicate Duderstadt results of $\sigma(E<<E_0)\propto 1/\sqrt{E}$ since I do not know if and how $\Gamma$ (the total decay width, not the neutron line width) and $\Gamma_\gamma$ (gamma ray emission width) depend from E (energy of incident neutron). The only thing I think I know is that for non relativistic particles $k^2=2mE/\hbar^2\propto E$, and obviously $\Gamma_n \propto \sqrt E$ as stated before.

If anyone has answer to either question it would mean a great deal, thank you in advance and please pardon any stackexchange etiquette imprecisions as this is my first ever post.

I always figured it was a ‘time in the nucleus’ effect.

@JonCuster Same for me — in fact that's how my PhD advisor explained it to me. But deriving this correspondence-principle result from the microscopic physics would be nifty.

Ok I managed to find a decent explanation in Bertulani's book, sec. 12.4. He even gives two different approaches to get to the $1/v$ dependence. I'm sorry I didn't find this out sooner.
Question #1 is still valid but #2 is pretty much irrelevant at this point.
@rob Should I edit this question, answer my own question with what I found or delete it?
Thank you both for your prompt replies

Oh, definitely answer the question!

I'm sorry I'm dumb: it was Krane's book, not Bertulani's.
I'll post the anwer as soon as I can

I found an explanation for the $1/v$ dependence for radiative capture, but more in general for all composite processes, in Krane's Introductory Nuclear Physics, 1988, section 12.4.
He actually supplies two different yet equivalent approaches, one based on the transmission probability of a spherical wave inciding on a rectangular potential well and the other based on the low energy limit for the Breit-Wigner formula.
Since the question revolved around the BW formula, I'm gonna use this latter formulation.
He basically notes that:

$k=p/\hbar$=$mv/\hbar \propto v$;
$\Gamma_n\propto v$: you can think of this as "somewhat similar to $\alpha$ decay, in which the decay probability includes a factor proportional to v that originates from considering the frequency with which the $\alpha$ particle presents itself to the nuclear barrier in preparation for decay";
$\Gamma_\gamma$ and $\Gamma$ are indipendent of $v$.

Therefore, from
\begin{equation}\label{eq: Breit-Wigner}
    \sigma_\gamma = \frac{\pi}{k^2} g \frac{\Gamma_{\gamma} \Gamma_{n}}{(E - E_R)^2 + \Gamma^2 / 4}
\end{equation}
for $E<<E_R \implies (E-E_R)^2\simeq E_R^2$, and substituting the above listed dependences we get:
\begin{equation}
    \sigma_\gamma \simeq \frac{\pi}{k^2} g \frac{\Gamma_{n} \Gamma_{\gamma}}{(E_R)^2 + \Gamma^2 / 4} \propto \frac{1}{v}
\end{equation}
I couldn't actually find how Duderstadt gets his $\sqrt{E_0/E}$ factor, but personally I don't really care, since I ended up on his explanation only because I couldn't seem to find one in Krane's or Bertulani's books, so I am satisfied any way.
EDIT:
I found a derivation of Duderstadt's formula in Bell, Glasstone - Nuclear Reactor Theory (1970), section 8.1b (pages 392 through 396).
This is the reaction cross section for channel $x$:

(N.B. $N$ is the number of target nuclei per unit volume, so this is technically a macroscopic cross section)
This is the scattering cross section (for s-wave neutrons):

Since $ƛ\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{E}}\implies ƛ=ƛ_0\sqrt{\frac{E_0}{E}}$.
If one evaluates both scattering and reaction cross sections in $E_0$, substituting the value of ƛ too, and adds them, one gets:
$$\sigma_0=4N\piƛ^2g\, \frac{\Gamma_n^2 + \Gamma_n\Gamma_x}{\Gamma^2}$$
But if one assumes that the total width $\Gamma$ made of only $\Gamma_x$ and $\Gamma_n$, then $\Gamma=\Gamma_n+\Gamma_x$ and factoring a $\Gamma_n$ at the numerator one gets:
$$\sigma_0=4N\piƛ^2g\, \frac{\Gamma_n(\Gamma_n + \Gamma_x)}{\Gamma (\Gamma_n+\Gamma_x)}=\sigma_0=4N\piƛ^2g\, \frac{\Gamma_n}{\Gamma}$$
Which is the same as Duderstadt's, minus the factor $N$. From here is just a matter of substituting $\sigma_0$ into the previous equations, so to get:

which is pretty much it.
